# How can I restrict decimal values from being entered in a input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have trouble restricting the input characters to integers only. Is there a way by which I can restrict the decimal numbers or float from being entered into the input type="`number`"?

I have also tried the following approach by replacing `.` with `''` whenever event for `keyup` is fired:

```js
$("#myForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("#number").on('keyup', function() {
  var regex = new RegExp(/\d+\.\d?/g);
  var number = $(this).val();
  if (regex.test(number)) {
    number = number.replace(/\./g, '');
    $(this).val(number);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="//google.de">
  <p>Input type number step 1</p>
  <input type="number" name="number" id="number" step="1" min="0"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

With the above code, following are the case results:

```
WORKS:
2.3

FAILS:
2..3
2….3
2.3.3.3.3.3.3.3.3.3.3.333...3
```

I need only 2 (any integer) to be allowed, and from all other cases (including the copy and paste), the decimal should be removed.

So my final question is that how can I restrict float numbers from being entered in the input field with `type="number"`? If that's not possible then how can I change the above code to meet my requirements?

**EDIT:**

Please do not close this question if this question partially matches another. I have written a code here too. I want to know, what's wrong with it.

Comment: I still haven't found out what's wrong with the above code @Andreas. What's the point in closing a question that partially matches another question.

Comment: try the following (returns integers only):     var res = number.replace(/\D/g, "");

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this. Neither Firefox, nor Chrome nor IE (10+) allow me to submit the form if the value isn't an integer just by adding `step="1"`: https://jsfiddle.net/zrgoh7fx/

Comment: @Andreas, if you could just look into the code that I have shared, then you would know that I have already added `step` and `min` to it. But, my concern here is to block the decimal point right at the moment when the user types `.`.